# What is the diameter of a Trent 900 engine?

Tags: jet-engine

What is the diameter of a Trent 900 engine, i.e the diameter of the fans, from one fan tip to the one that is directly opposite it? What is the radius of the fan or the the length of each fan blade?

Answer (score 6):

The Trent 900 fan diameter is [295cm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Trent_900#Specifications_.28Trent_900.29).